# Converting scanLocation from utf16 units to character index in NSScanner (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, unicode, swift3, nsscanner

In Swift 3.0 (NS)Scanner, `string` property returns the string being parsed and `scanLocation` returns the current scan location. I'm trying to extract the parsed text:

```
var parsedText: String {
    return string.substring(to: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: scanLocation))
}
```

This code crashes when `string` contains multibyte characters. It turned out that `scanLocation` returns number of utf16 units, not number of characters parsed.

How to convert scanLocation (code units) into character index?

Playground for experimenting:

```
let scanner = Scanner(string: "Hello")
scanner.scanString("Hello", into: nil)
print(scanner.scanLocation) // Returns 7 instead of 6
```

Answer (score 2):

To obtain character index:

```
import Foundation

extension Scanner {
    var scanLocationInCharacters: Int {
        let utf16 = string.utf16
        guard let to16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: scanLocation, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: string) else {
                return 0
        }
        return string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: to)
    }
}

let scanner = Scanner(string: "Hello")
scanner.scanString("Hello", into: nil)

print(scanner.scanLocation) // 7
print(scanner.scanLocationInCharacters) // 6
```

To retrieve parsed text:

```
var parsedText: String {
    let utf16 = string.utf16
    guard let to16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: scanLocation, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
        let to = String.Index(to16, within: string) else {
            return ""
    }
    return string.substring(to: to)
}
```

*Bonus:* when reporting errors, you'll probably want to print current line and column as well:

```
var currentLine: Int {
    var lineCount = 1
    for character in parsedText.characters {
        if character == "\n" { lineCount += 1 }
    }
    return lineCount
}

var currentColumn: Int {
    let text = parsedText
    if let range = text.range(of: "\n", options: .backwards) {
        return text.distance(from: range.upperBound, to: text.endIndex) + 1
    }
    return parsedText.characters.count + 1
}
```